# Disable auto resizing GridBagLayout (Java)

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm creating a java desktop app for drinks orders, and I use GridBagLayout.
But all elements are automatically resized...
I made some research on Google and this website but I did not found what I want...

This is my app:

[Screenshot of my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SWWG.png)

So as you can see I have two sides : left side contains buttons and right side contains order content and some utilities. But all buttons don't have the same size (its resized automatically with GridBagLayout) and sometimes the right side is resized too (it depends of what items I put on the left side). I'd like to disable this auto-resize. I already tried with panel.setMaximumSize() but it failed for me.

Comment: What do you mean with "all buttons don't have the same size"?

Comment: @MoritzPetersen All buttons don't have the same width if you check it :/

Comment: Put the `JButtons` in their own `JPanel` using a `GridLayout`.  Put the Commands display in a separate `JPanel` with a `FlowLayout`.  Put the two `JButtons` in the lower right in a third `JPanel` with a `BoxLayout`.  Put the Commands display `JPanel` and the two `JButtons` `JPanel` in a control `JPanel` with a `BorderLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The size and resize behavior can be adjusted using

```
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
c.weightx = 1.0;
```

for all buttons.

Comment: I tried but all buttons are resized because of the text inside. If the text is longer, the width of the button will change...